# Rails error param is missing or the value is empty: history

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to create a functionality in which from my index I press a button and it will execute an action in the controller in which I made it. Everything is fine until in my controller they show that the values ​​of certain parameters are or are empty. I appreciate the help. [Image Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2elYJ.png)

My index.html.erb

```
<tbody>
  <% undefined = "No definido" %>
  <% @histories.each do |history| %>
  <% if history.history_status == "publicada" %>
   <tr>
    <td><%= history.title %></td>
    <td><%= history.description %></td>
    <td><%= history.history_status %></td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
     <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Acciones
        <span class="caret">
        </span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" role="menu">
        <li style="background-color:#337ab7; text-align: center;">
           <%= link_to "Ver Historia", admin_history_path(history)%>
        </li>
        <li style="background-color:#d9534f; text-align: center;">
            <%= link_to 'Rechazar Historia', admin_rechazar_historia_path(history), :title => history.title, :description => history.description, method: :patch, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
        </li>
        <li style="background-color:#f0ad4e; text-align: center;">
            <%= link_to 'Eliminar Historia', admin_inactivar_historia_path(history), :title => history.title, :description => history.description, method: :patch, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
        </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
 <% end %>  
 <% end %>
</tbody>
```

My history_controller.rb

```
class Admin::HistoriesController < Admin::BaseController

    before_action :set_history, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :publicar_historia, :inactivar_historia, :rechazar_historia]

    def new
        @history = History.new
        @image = @history.images.build
    end

    def edit
        @image = @history.images.build
    end

    def create
        @history = History.new(history_params)
        @history.assign_attributes({:user_id => current_user.id})
        @history.assign_attributes({:history_status => 'publicada'})

        if @history.save
        params[:images]['picture'].each do |a|
            @image = @history.images.create!(:picture => a)
        end
            flash[:success] = "Historia creada exitosamente"
            redirect_to admin_histories_path
        else
            flash.now[:danger] = "La Historia no se pudo crear, por favor revise los campos"
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def show
        @images = @history.images.all
    end

    def index
        @histories = History.all
    end

    def update
        @history.assign_attributes({:history_status => 'publicada'})
        if @history.update(history_params)
            flash[:success] = "Historia actualizada exitosamente"
            redirect_to admin_histories_path
        else
            flash[:warnig] = "Historia no actualizada"
            redirect_to admin_histories_path
        end
    end

    def inactivar_historia
        @history.assign_attributes({:history_status => 'inactiva'})
        if @history.update(history_params)
            flash[:success] = "Historia actualizada exitosamente"
            redirect_to admin_histories_path
        else
            flash[:warnig] = "Historia no actualizada"
            redirect_to admin_histories_path
        end
    end

    def publicar_historia
        @history.assign_attributes({:history_status => 'publicada'})
        if @history.update(history_params)
            flash[:success] = "Historia actualizada exitosamente"
            redirect_to admin_histories_path
        else
            flash[:warnig] = "Historia no actualizada"
            redirect_to admin_histories_path
        end
    end

    def rechazar_historia
       @history.assign_attributes({:history_status => 'rechazada'})
       if @history.update(history_params)
            flash[:success] = "Historia actualizada exitosamente"
            redirect_to admin_histories_path
       else
            flash[:warnig] = "Historia no actualizada"
            redirect_to admin_histories_path
       end
    end

    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_history
        @history = History.find(params[:id])
    end

    def history_params
        params.require(:history).permit(:title, :description,images_attributes: [:id, :picture, :history_id])
    end


end
```

And my route.db

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
    resources :histories 
  end

  namespace :admin do
    patch "inactivar_historia/:id" => "histories#inactivar_historia", :as => :inactivar_historia
    patch "publicar_historia/:id" => "histories#publicar_historia", :as => :publicar_historia
    patch "rechazar_historia/:id" => "histories#rechazar_historia", :as => :rechazar_historia
  end
end
```

The error is: 
ActionController::ParameterMissing at /admin/rechazar_historia/2
param is missing or the value is empty: history

The _form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for [:admin, @history], html: {multipart: true} do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :title, label: "Título", required: true, autofocus: true %>

  <%= f.input :description, label: "Descripcion", required: true, autofocus: true %>

  <%= f.fields_for :images do |p| %>
    <div class="field">

      <%= p.label :picture %><br>
      <%= p.file_field :picture, :multiple => true, name: "images[picture][]" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

 <p>
 <br>

 <div class="actions">
   <%= f.submit %>
 </div>
```

Comment: Do you have a form you're using too? And is this on submission of a form/record? Essentially it looks like one of your actions that call `history_params` is being sent `params` that don't take the format `{ history: { title: "whatever", .... } }` (it's missing the history key) so I'm suspecting a form issue

Comment: there add the _form that I use

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling `@history.update(history_paramas)` on `rechazar_historia`? you don't need that line and that's the error.

You have a link to that action so there's no params[:history]. I guess you just copied the `update` action on for the other actions, but you don't really need to update the whole object on all the actions, you are not passing any data (and you shouldn't since the action is not "update", it's "reject").

Just change those `@history.update(history_params)` with `@history.save` and it should work.

Comment: I thought that with @ history.save I was going to create a new object, I edited it and acmodé in the slineas and it works. Thank you so much.